# Tests cases are passing in bamboo but build is failing with the error 'No failed test found. A possible compilation error occurred'

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng

The same script is working fine on my local system. The built takes 1hour and 19 minutes to deploy on  bamboo.But it takes maximum 2 minutes for a successfully built on my local machine.On the  the Local machine I am using Windows but deplying server is Linux.

**This is my Logs File:**

```
    

 

       06-Jul-2022 10:23:35 Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [INFO] Total time:  01:49 h
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-06T10:23:35Z
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test (default-test) on project Provider: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException: 
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR] Cannot instantiate class Test_Scenarios.Main
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:30)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:423)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:336)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:125)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:190)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:95)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:81)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:73)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:38)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:389)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:271)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:241)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:167)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:663)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:260)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:198)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1295)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1273)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:178)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:92)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:96)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:159)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:87)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:95)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:24)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         ... 32 more
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR] Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR] Build info: version: '4.1.2', revision: '9a5a329c5a'
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR] System info: host: 'stella-infra-build2', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-1080-aws', java.version: '1.8.0_275'
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR] Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR] Command: [8e4b7d61e83a8a00e6d0c3466504e582, get {url= https://qa-verato.stella-apps.com/}]
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR] Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 103.0.5060.53, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 103.0.5060.53 (a1711811edd7..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.pwuFOE}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:38107}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:38107/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 103.0.5060.53, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR] Session ID: 8e4b7d61e83a8a00e6d0c3466504e582
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:72)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.RetryRequest.lambda$apply$6(RetryRequest.java:80)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at net.jodah.failsafe.Functions.lambda$get$0(Functions.java:48)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at net.jodah.failsafe.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$supply$0(RetryPolicyExecutor.java:66)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at net.jodah.failsafe.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$supply$0(RetryPolicyExecutor.java:66)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at net.jodah.failsafe.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$supply$0(RetryPolicyExecutor.java:66)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at net.jodah.failsafe.Execution.executeSync(Execution.java:128)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at net.jodah.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.call(FailsafeExecutor.java:379)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at net.jodah.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.get(FailsafeExecutor.java:68)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.RetryRequest.lambda$apply$7(RetryRequest.java:80)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.execute(NettyHttpHandler.java:51)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.RetryRequest.lambda$apply$6(RetryRequest.java:80)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at net.jodah.failsafe.Functions.lambda$get$0(Functions.java:48)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at net.jodah.failsafe.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$supply$0(RetryPolicyExecutor.java:66)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at net.jodah.failsafe.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$supply$0(RetryPolicyExecutor.java:66)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at net.jodah.failsafe.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$supply$0(RetryPolicyExecutor.java:66)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at net.jodah.failsafe.Execution.executeSync(Execution.java:128)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at net.jodah.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.call(FailsafeExecutor.java:379)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at net.jodah.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.get(FailsafeExecutor.java:68)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.RetryRequest.lambda$apply$7(RetryRequest.java:80)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.execute(NettyClient.java:110)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:181)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:558)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:327)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at Utils.BrowserManager.getDriver(BrowserManager.java:64)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at Test_Scenarios.Main.<init>(Main.java:19)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         ... 37 more
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR] Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1784)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1928)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyResponseFuture.java:206)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:66)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR]         ... 68 more
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR] 
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR] 
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    Failing task since return code of [/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn --batch-mode -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/bamboo/current/temp/VER-VERPRSE-JOB1 test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=testng.xml] was 1 while expected 0
06-Jul-2022 10:23:35    Parsing test results under /data/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/VER-VERPRSE-JOB1...
06-Jul-2022 10:23:36    File /data/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/VER-VERPRSE-JOB1/target/surefire-reports/testng-failed.xml was ignored because it was modified (2022-06-30 12:17:25.000) before task started (2022-07-06 08:33:50.746)
06-Jul-2022 10:23:36    Finished task 'Selenium Test' with result
```

**This is My Test File:**

```
public class Main {
    String browser = "chrome";
    String url = " https://example.com/";
    WebDriver driver = BrowserManager.getDriver(browser, url);



    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    

    @Test(priority = 1)
    @Parameters({ "browser", "url" })
    void PS_01_User_Login() throws InterruptedException {

        VerificationPage verPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, VerificationPage.class);
        LoginPage page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
        MailinatorPage mailPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, MailinatorPage.class);

        page.enterUserName();
        page.enterUserPassword();
        page.clickLoginButton();
        mailPage.waiting();
        mailPage.visitMailinator();

        verPage.clickOnAccessPortalBtn();
    }




    @AfterSuite

    public void aftertest() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.quit();

      }
    }
```

**This is my POM file:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <groupId>ProviderStewardShip</groupId>
        <artifactId>Provider</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
        <name>Provider</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beust/jcommander -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
                <version>1.82</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>6.14.3</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
    
    
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.webdriver/webdriver-selenium -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.webdriver</groupId>
                <artifactId>webdriver-selenium</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.7376</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
                <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <reporting>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                </plugin>
    
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
    
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </reporting>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
    
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.14.1</version>
    
                    <configuration>
                        <forkCount>3</forkCount>
                        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project>
```

Comment: Enough memory?.

Comment: How to check memory? @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Comment: First you are using plugins (surefire-plugin of 2013).. you are using junit 3.8.1 (2007?), you are using testng: 2018 ... please upgrade your dependencies, the plugins you are using etc. make a decision which testing framework you would like to use and you are not following naming conventsions for test. Unit tests should be like `*Test.java` etc. and integration tests should be like `*IT.java` and more important executed by maven-failsave-plugin etc. having a dependency to jcommander? etc.

Comment: Do you or a senior developer have command line access to the system? Does the system have internet access (some features may require this)?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, yes I have

Comment: Figure out how to attach a profiler like visualvm or a debugger and find out where the time is spent.  This is very useful to know because you will need to do it again